# Custom DataAnnotations attribute to Fluent-API

Tags: entity-framework-core, data-annotations, ef-fluent-api

I'm porting aproject from EF6 to EF7 Core and I'm converting all the classes with DataAnnotationtions to FluentAPI.

In the project I have extensive use of Custom DataAnnotatiotions Attributes. I'm in the need to convert:

```
    [Required, MaxLength(Consts.DbLength.OriginName)]
    [FrontendEditable]
    public string OriginName { get; set; }
```

where [FrontendEditable] is something like:

```
    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property | AttributeTargets.Enum, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = false)]
public class FrontendEditableAttribute : Attribute
{
    public FrontendEditableAttribute()
    {
    }
```

I would like to convert this to Fluent API in the modelBuilder like:

```
            modelBuilder.Entity<Origin>(e =>
        {
            e.Property(oN => oN.OriginName).IsRequired();
            e.Property(oN => oN.OriginName).HasColumnType("NVARCHAR");
            e.Property(oN => oN.OriginName).HasMaxLength(50);
        });
```

This in order to have only some of the fields of the db editable from the FrontEnd and some locked.

Any suggestion will be appreciated.